# how to create session using mongodb in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session

i am trying to create session with mongodb in node.js
already i have a connection like this

```
var Db=require('mongodb').Db;


var BSON=require('mongodb').BSONPure;

var Server=require('mongodb').Server;


 var client=new Db('db',new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:false});
```

and then i have tried to configure session like this

```
 app.use(express.session({

   store: new mongoStore({ db: client }),
    secret: 'topsecret'

   }));
```

i ran the server.js file i got this error mongoStore undefined 
so to resolve this error i have added this

```
  var mongoStore= require('connect-mongodb');
```

again i ran it i did't get any error but i got below error   when i tried to find or save data into db

```
    Cannot call method 'findOne' of undefined
```

how to resolve this problem and how to create session with mongodb in node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very simple setup:

```
var express     = require('express');
var MongoStore  = require('connect-mongo')(express);
var app         = express();

app.use(express.cookieParser()); // required to handle session cookies!
app.use(express.session({
  secret  : 'YOUR_SESSION_SECRET',
  cookie  : {
    maxAge  : 10000              // expire the session(-cookie) after 10 seconds
  },
  store   : new MongoStore({
    db: 'sessionstore'
    // see https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo#options for more options
  })
}));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  var previous      = req.session.value || 0;
  req.session.value = previous + 1;
  res.send('<h1>Previous value: ' + previous + '</h1>');
});

app.listen(3012);
```

If you run it and open `http://localhost:3012/` in your browser, it will increase the value by 1 each time you reload. After 10 seconds, the session will expire and the value will be reset to 0.